# Stop range slider from crossing each other HTML CSS

Tags: html, css, angular, frontend

I have created range slider with two button but it crosses each other I want they should not cross each other value of first button should be equal to min-value of second and max-value of first button should be equal to value of second button and it should only show selected range in brown rest all should be white.

Here is my code

```
.range_container {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  margin-top: 30px;
}

.sliders-control {
  position: relative;
}

.form_control {
  position: relative;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  font-size: 24px;
  color: #635a5a;
}

input[type=range]::-webkit-slider-thumb {
  -webkit-appearance: none;
  pointer-events: all;
  width: 15px;
  height: 15px;
  background-color: #fff;
  border-radius: 50%;
  box-shadow: 1px 1px 1px 1px gray;
  cursor: pointer;
}

input[type=range]::-moz-range-thumb {
  -moz-appearance: none;
  pointer-events: all;
  width: 15px;
  height: 15px;
  background-color: #fff;
  border-radius: 50%;
  box-shadow: 1px 1px 1px 1px gray;
  cursor: pointer;
 }

 input[type="range"] {
  -webkit-appearance: none;
  appearance: none;
  height: 10px;
  width: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  background-color: brown;
  pointer-events: none;
  border-radius: 10px;
  border: 1px solid black;
}

.values{
  background-color: #3264fe;
  width: 32%;
  position: relative;
  margin: auto;
  padding: 10px 0;
  border-radius: 5px;
  text-align: center;
  font-weight: 500;
  font-size: 25px;
  color: #ffffff;
}
.values:before{
   content: "";
   position: absolute;
   height: 0;
   width: 0;
   border-top: 15px solid #3264fe;
   border-left: 15px solid transparent;
   border-right: 15px solid transparent;
   margin: auto;
   bottom: -14px;
   left: 0;
   right: 0;
}

#fromSlider {
  height: 0;
  z-index: 1;
  top: 5px;
  background: none;
  border: none;
}

#min-value {
  float: left;
}

#max-value {
  float: right;
}

<span id="min-value">&#x20b9;{{value1}}</span> <span id="max-value">&#x20b9;{{value2}}</span>
<div class="range_container">
  <div class="sliders-control">
    <input id="fromSlider" type="range" step="500" [(ngModel)] = "value1" value="{{value1}}" min="7000" max="100000" />
    <input id="toSlider" type="range" step="500" [(ngModel)] = "value2" value="{{value2}}" min="7000" max="100000" />
  </div>
</div>
```

output:

[image: Here is the output]

required

[image: Here is what I need]

I don't want slider button to cross each other.

Comment: add a check in the input event handlers for each slider.

Comment: I added a check on (change) but it moves to very start or very end of the slider @Sachin

Comment: Check the answer @Vaibhav More

Comment: `min-value` can be the same as `max-value`? or `min-value` **must** be smaller than `max-value`?

Comment: It must be smaller than max value and also about the color only selected range should be brown rest should be gray@JShobbyist

Comment: @VaibhavMore, did you check my answer?

Answer (score 1):

I hope this is exactly what you're looking for. I added some javascript code to manage the range slider and the buttons.

```js
function controlFromSlider(fromSlider, toSlider) {
  const [from, to] = getParsed(fromSlider, toSlider);
  fillSlider(fromSlider, toSlider, '#C6C6C6', 'brown', toSlider);
  if (from >= to) {
    fromSlider.value = to-500;
  }
}

function controlToSlider(fromSlider, toSlider) {
  const [from, to] = getParsed(fromSlider, toSlider);
  fillSlider(fromSlider, toSlider, '#C6C6C6', 'brown', toSlider);
  setToggleAccessible(toSlider);
  if (from <= to) {
    toSlider.value = to;
  } else {
    toSlider.value = from+500;
  }
}

function getParsed(currentFrom, currentTo) {
  const from = parseInt(currentFrom.value, 10);
  const to = parseInt(currentTo.value, 10);
  return [from, to];
}

function fillSlider(from, to, sliderColor, rangeColor, controlSlider) {
  const rangeDistance = to.max - to.min;
  const fromPosition = from.value - to.min;
  const toPosition = to.value - to.min;
  controlSlider.style.background = `linear-gradient(
      to right,
      ${sliderColor} 0%,
      ${sliderColor} ${(fromPosition)/(rangeDistance)*100}%,
      ${rangeColor} ${((fromPosition)/(rangeDistance))*100}%,
      ${rangeColor} ${(toPosition)/(rangeDistance)*100}%, 
      ${sliderColor} ${(toPosition)/(rangeDistance)*100}%, 
      ${sliderColor} 100%)`;
}

function setToggleAccessible(currentTarget) {
  const toSlider = document.querySelector('#toSlider');
  if (Number(currentTarget.value) <= 0) {
    toSlider.style.zIndex = 2;
  } else {
    toSlider.style.zIndex = 0;
  }
}

const fromSlider = document.querySelector('#fromSlider');
const toSlider = document.querySelector('#toSlider');
fillSlider(fromSlider, toSlider, '#C6C6C6', 'brown', toSlider);
setToggleAccessible(toSlider);

fromSlider.oninput = () => controlFromSlider(fromSlider, toSlider);
toSlider.oninput = () => controlToSlider(fromSlider, toSlider);
```

```css
.range_container {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  margin-top: 30px;
}

.sliders-control {
  position: relative;
}

.form_control {
  position: relative;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  font-size: 24px;
  color: #635a5a;
}

input[type=range]::-webkit-slider-thumb {
  -webkit-appearance: none;
  pointer-events: all;
  width: 15px;
  height: 15px;
  background-color: #fff;
  border-radius: 50%;
  box-shadow: 1px 1px 1px 1px gray;
  cursor: pointer;
}

input[type=range]::-moz-range-thumb {
  -moz-appearance: none;
  pointer-events: all;
  width: 15px;
  height: 15px;
  background-color: #fff;
  border-radius: 50%;
  box-shadow: 1px 1px 1px 1px gray;
  cursor: pointer;
}

input[type="range"] {
  -webkit-appearance: none;
  appearance: none;
  height: 10px;
  width: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  background-color: brown;
  pointer-events: none;
  border-radius: 10px;
  border: 1px solid black;
}

.values {
  background-color: #3264fe;
  width: 32%;
  position: relative;
  margin: auto;
  padding: 10px 0;
  border-radius: 5px;
  text-align: center;
  font-weight: 500;
  font-size: 25px;
  color: #ffffff;
}

.values:before {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  height: 0;
  width: 0;
  border-top: 15px solid #3264fe;
  border-left: 15px solid transparent;
  border-right: 15px solid transparent;
  margin: auto;
  bottom: -14px;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
}

#fromSlider {
  height: 0;
  z-index: 1;
  top: 6px;
  background: none;
  border: none;
}

#min-value {
  float: left;
}

#max-value {
  float: right;
}
```

```html
<span id="min-value">&#x20b9;{{value1}}</span> <span id="max-value">&#x20b9;{{value2}}</span>
<div class="range_container">
  <div class="sliders-control">
    <input id="fromSlider" type="range" step="500" [(ngModel)]="value1" value="{{value1}}" min="7000" max="100000" />
    <input id="toSlider" type="range" step="500" [(ngModel)]="value2" value="{{value2}}" min="7000" max="100000" />
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Love to help you.  would you check my answer?

Comment: Yes this is what I needed but I don't want thumbs to overlap each other there should be a gap between them

Comment: If so, how much the min value should be smaller than the max value? Let's assume that the right button(max value) is 8000. If so, what the left button can reach as possible as it can?

Comment: @VaibhavMore, did you resolve this?

Answer (score -1):

```
sliderChanged(event: any) {

  const value = event.target.value;
  const id = event.target.id;

  
  if ((id === 'fromSlider' && value > this.value2) || (id === 'toSlider' && value < this.value1)) {
    if (id === 'fromSlider') {
      this.value2 = value;
    } else {
      this.value1 = value;
    }
  }
}
```

Bind the event handler to `input` event of each slider. Remove the `value` attribute as `[(ngModel)]` syntax is used for two-way data binding in Angular

```
 <input id="fromSlider" type="range" step="500" [(ngModel)]="value1" min="7000" max="100000" (input)="sliderChanged($event)" />
<input id="toSlider" type="range" step="500" [(ngModel)]="value2" min="7000" max="100000" (input)="sliderChanged($event)" />
```

Comment: I tested this, but got `"Uncaught SyntaxError: missing ) after argument list"`